# Data Visualization software for java in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, data-visualization, pie-chart, graph-visualization

I did Sentiment analysis and I have a positive and negative score as the output. I want to show these data as a Pie Chart. Can you guys suggest me a simple-to-use APIs/JARs that i can use to achieve my goal?. I have Eclipse Juno. I did a basic Google search and i got only GWT-Visualization 1.0.2.jar . I prefer to use a simpler one than this if it exits.
I don't have Maven and since I want to get this over with by today, I don't have time to install and learn new software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/

I have used this one before and it's very simple and straightforward to use.
In the website you will find many examples of pie charts.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

For Desktop application can also consider the [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html)

For Web Application can also consider [Ext](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/sandbox/sandbox.html), GWT.